# Data table in jquery not refreshing data live

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web, datatable

I have a data table and using ajax to fetch data and display on my html DOM page. But the problem is after implement the server-side processing for the data table I finally have records in my html table through ajax but when I make a change in my database the change is not getting reflected in my data table until and unless I refresh the page. Then what's the benifit of using ajax in data table that you still have to refresh the page to see the changes

My ajax code to select the data

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#example').DataTable( {
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "rendringMain.php"
} );
```

My rendringMain.php is exectly the same like this link https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html but few changes

Comment: ajax is used to send data from the client to the server, not the other way around. I believe you will have to make use of something like websockets if you want the datatable updated live. Either that or you refresh the datatable at regular intervals by making an ajax call to the server.

Comment: @H77 can you help me with websockets. I am new and don't where to start

Comment: Sorry that would be too broad to explain here. Google is your friend... Periodically refreshing the datatable would be a much simpler solution though.

Comment: @H77 I understand, but learning websockets will be a long process. I need this for my office assignment. Can we make something in javascript that refresh the page automatically when-ever we make changes?

Comment: `>Then what's the benifit of using ajax in data table that you still have to refresh the page to see the changes`

You can make ajax-call to request updated data let's say on `refresh` button, as example. And you can update your table data without refreshing whole page - just get data in callback for this ajax-call and put it wherever it suppose to be

Comment: @DanilGholtsman yep, that's what I am think to do now, as websockets will take time for me to learn and implement at this particular time.Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use following solution to refresh your datatable at every 5 seconds:

```
window.setInterval( 
$("table[id='example']").DataTable().ajax.reload();
, 5000);
```

Comment: Oh wow, I really appreciate. That's a brilliant idea . Thank you.